# Docker Run two unending programs python

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to run a flask server (app.py) and a script which, evry 5 minutes, sends a request to that server.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

COPY ./requirement.txt /app/requirement.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt
COPY ./src /app

EXPOSE 8022

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["metricRequester.py &"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

**metricRequester.py**

```
import sched, time
import requests

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def sendRequest(sc):
    print("Sending Request")
    requestString = "http://127.0.0.1:8022/"
    try:
        response = requests.get(requestString)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't send request")
        print(e)
    print("Request sent")
    sc.enter(300, 1, sendRequest, (sc,))

s.enter(300, 1, sendRequest, (s,))
s.run()
```

When I run the app.py and metricRequester on my laptop they both work correctly.

I am trying to make a local dockerfile which runs both of these scripts.

With my current dockerfile, only the app.py seems to be running. It is reachable on port 8022. But I am not seeing any metrics emails coming through, indicating that metricRequester.py is not running.

How do I rewrite my Dockerfile to allow for both scripts to run.

Comment: `Dockerfile`s are used to *build* Docker *images*. They are not used to *run* Docker *containers*.

Comment: You need to `docker run` two separate containers, one for each program.  They can use the same image if that's convenient for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal setup is to have one process running in one container. So it's good to run `app.py` and `metricRequestr.py` in two separate containers. So have two Dockerfiles:

Dockerfile 1:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

COPY ./requirement.txt /app/requirement.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt
COPY ./src /app

EXPOSE 8022

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["metricRequester.py"]
```

Dockerfile2:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

COPY ./requirement.txt /app/requirement.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt
COPY ./src /app

EXPOSE 8022

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

The Ports will vary for each containers.